Analysis Services and Power BI refreshes after publishing
We had three reports connected to Tyler Munis that were hosted locally. The cubes connected and refreshed fine when it was set up this way. Now that we have moved to the cloud, the desktop Power BI connects without issue to the cubes, but once it is deployed to the Power BI service, we cannot set it up to auto-refresh. The on-premises gateway is working without issue on other refreshes, and it's up-to-date.
The connection is a URL: https://XXX.tylerhost.net
Username: tylerhost/XXX
Connecting via on-premises gateway:
Unable to create connection for the following reason: The on-premises data gateway's service account failed to impersonate the user.
Details: [GATEWAY SERVER]: Received error payload from gateway service with ID 101173: Error logging on username.
Status code: 400
Connection type: Analysis Services

Connecting to the cube via Cloud:
Unable to create connection for the following reason: The authentication type is not supported. Only the authentication type 'Windows' is supported.
Details:
Status code: 400
Connection type: Analysis Services

For the cloud option, only Basic and OAuth are options, and both throw the same error: Windows is the only option. I connect on the desktop via Basic and cannot connect with Windows (alternate credentials) or a Microsoft Account.
I found this question from 2019, but I'm hoping it is old information (see the second, longer answer).
I checked the data gateway logs to ensure no unusual errors were thrown (besides what it already says on the service).
I also attempted to change the Power BI Desktop connection to Web (instead of Analysis Services) and received a connection error after inputting my login information. I attempted to use my login credentials as Windows alternative credentials as well (desktop), but Power BI wouldn't let me authenticate. Basic is the only way the cube allows me to connect on the desktop.
